# How to test whether extreme price deviations are correlated?

Tags: time-series, correlation, panel-data, cross-correlation

I have a panel data set of the minute-by-minute OHLC (i.e. Open, High, Low, Close) prices of Bitcoin from multiple exchanges.

I would like to test whether the extreme price deviations (i.e. the difference between the high and the open prices, or the low and the open prices) are correlated across the different exchanges. In other words, I want to test if a large price jump in Bitcoin on one exchange is in any way correlated/coordinated with an extreme price jump on another exchange.

While the Bitcoin prices are correlated in general terms, I am more interested in the extreme events.

I am not exactly sure how to tackle such a problem. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: “Cokurtosis” might be a term worth exploring. // While this question is 100% on-topic here and gets a +1 from me (I’d like to see more questions here about high-order cross-moments), you might have better luck on the quantitative finance Stack, quant.stackexchange.com.